# Special characters, wcin and getline - strange behaviour

Tags: c++

I have a problem with reading special characters (Polish) from console to `wstring`. Here is the code:

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale("pl_PL.UTF-8"));
    std::wcout.imbue(std::locale("pl_PL.UTF-8")); 
    std::wcin.imbue(std::locale("pl_PL.UTF-8")); 
    std::wstring brand;
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        std::wcout << L"Name: ";
        std::getline(std::wcin, brand);
        std::wcout << brand << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is examplary input/output:

```
Name: abc abc
abc abc
Name: abc abć
abc abbć
Name: abć abc
abbć abc
Name: ąbc
翿ąbc
Name: ąbć
翿ąbbć
Name: ąbć ąbć
翿ąbbć  ąbbć
```

How do I fix this?
I am using MacOS, clang++ as a compiler and iTerm as a terminal

Comment: Where are you displaying the output? Terminal? What is $LANG?

Comment: On a terminal. iTerm's character encoding is set to UTF-8, macOS is in Polish

Comment: Have you tried using `std::wistream::getline` instead of `std::getline`? ( don't have that locale on any of my dev boxes, so I get an "invalid locale" exception when I try to run it and am too tired to add a new locale right now).

Comment: I have not, but it does not compile at all when I try to:
`error: call to non-static member function without an object argument`. Anyway, I have managed to overcome this problem, but with using ISO 8859-2 instead of UTF-8 (and changed terminal's encoding to iso latin-2). Not the best solution, but it works.